# Creating only one table in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to create a table only once while executing the same procedure several times eg:

```
create procedure grg 
    (@firstname varchar(100),
     @lastname varchar(100), 
     @dob date,
     @loginID varchar(100),
     @password varchar(100),
     @email varchar(100),
     @SSN varchar(11)
    )
as
begin 
     create table............ <- only once

     select 
         @firstname, @lastname, 
         @dob, @loginID, @password, @email,
         @SSN 

     If(.....)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

Keep in mind the if the table already exists it will show a warning not an error.

You can ignore the warning. If you want to temporarily disable the warning you can do it as follows.

```
SET sql_notes = 0;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
SET sql_notes = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah with sql you can use temp tables just prefix them with a hash.

> #

These tables would only exist on the current session

---

If you really want the stored proc to handle the creation of the table then you can create the table on the stored procedure's definition. Just make sure to validate if table already exists so you don't get errors.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XX
 AS
   BEGIN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = <table_name>)
        BEGIN
            <---INSERT CREATE TABLE SCRIPT HERE---->
        END

     <---POPULATE HERE--->


   END
```

Comment: but I want to be able to insert data into the same temp table without the table recreating and losing all the previously inserted data

Comment: Would your insert need data from the previous execution of the procedure?

Comment: yes. I need the user to be able to sign up and login again, be able to change password, etc.

Comment: If the table does not have to be destroyed, then maybe you could just create a real table then just populate it normally?

Comment: Or do you need a table PER user? @user7364229

Comment: no i dont need a table per user and I want to see if i can create the table just once within a stored procedure to populate many different users.

Comment: it's definitely possible with a stored proc. what i dont understand is why you have to perform the creation of the table on the stored procedure rather than create the table normally. anyway, i'll update my answer to try to answer your problem

Comment: im looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE grg
(@firstname VARCHAR(100),
 @lastname  VARCHAR(100),
 @dob       DATE,
 @loginID   VARCHAR(100),
 @password  VARCHAR(100),
 @email     VARCHAR(100),
 @SSN       VARCHAR(11)
)
AS
     BEGIN
         IF NOT EXISTS
         (
             SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'myTable' AND xtype = 'U'
         )
             BEGIN
                 CREATE TABLE myTable(Name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL);
             END;

         SELECT * FROM myTable;
     END;
```